# How to select the first row/line from database

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to make a java program program can takes just one row/line from phpMyAdmin database. what I mean is in the photo  [image]

The problem is that I couldnt figure out how to take just the first line because its always keep giving me all the id'S , dafat's , etc. Is there any way I can get every line alone or even every data alone (jsut 1 id from the first line for example). I would appreciate who can help me with this.

```
 Connection con = myConnection.getconnection();
    try{
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `id`, `dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` FROM "+ff1+"  WHERE 1 ");
        ResultSet resultset = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(resultset.getString("id"));


    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: Use `LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `id`, `dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` FROM "+ff1+"  LİMİT 1 ");

You mena like this ?

Comment: Yes, give it a try

Comment: What iritates me which row exactly do you want. There mus be somekind of order to define the first

Comment: @nbk As long as OP doesn't state any particular order, order by is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LIMIT` clause:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT `id`, `dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` FROM "
    + ff1 + " LIMIT 1");
```

If you want the first `id` value (the smallest one) you can combine with `ORDER BY`, as in:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT `id`, `dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` FROM "
    + ff1 + " ORDER BY id LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: there should be an ORDER BY for the LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Replace WHERE whit LIMIT

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `id`, `dafat`, `sinif`, `adet`, `price`, `type`, `total` FROM "+ff1+" ORDER BY id  LIMIT 1 ");
```

Comment: there should be an ORDER BY for the LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Use Rownum in your where clause like:

```
"SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE rownum < 2"
```

https://mfaisal1521.blogspot.com/2020/04/rownum-in-sql.html

And also resultset.getString("id") start fetch result from first index of query untill we dont move our cursor to next resultset.